# Is Heroku's .netrc file safe from infiltration by other programs? How does Heroku ensure that its tokens can't be used maliciously?

Tags: security, heroku, terminal, token

If Heroku's .netrc file can be accessed by simply running

```
cat ~/.netrc
```

and exposing the tokens, how do they ensure that the tokens can't be used by malicious software?

Comment: It's not "Heroku's" `.netrc` file. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc

Comment: Take a look at [Is it safe to use .netrc files to store credentials for tools like curl or ftp?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/94572/87611) from [security.se]. TL;DR: there's nothing preventing another program from using those credentials (but this is largely true of any credentials you store locally).